# Cardinality of Infinite/Finite Set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be a proper infinite subset of some set $X$. If $x$ and $y$ are two distinct elements of $X$ that are not in $A$, we may set $B = \{x, y\}\cup A$. What is the cardinality of $B$ in terms of the cardinality of $A$? Justify your answer.

I am thinking that $\operatorname{Card}(B) = 2 + \operatorname{Card}(A)$, but I am not sure (It seems too easy). If this is correct, would the justification be that 
$\operatorname{Card}(B) = \operatorname{Card}(\{x,y\} \cup A) = \operatorname{Card}(\{x,y\}) + \operatorname{Card}(A) = 2 + \operatorname{Card}(A)$?

Comment: $\text{Infinite cardinality}+\text{finite cardinality}=\ldots ?$

Comment: Is the axiom of choice available?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $|B|=2+|A|$, but, as $A$ is infinite, $$2+|A|=|A|\,,$$
 as you can find a bijection between $B$ and $A$, shifting $2$ elements of $A$ towards the infinity.

Comment: I understand now why 2 + |A| = |A| and so |B| = |A|, but could you explain further how there is a bijection between B and A.

Comment: There is already a bijection between A and $\mathbb{Z}$, so let's number the elements $a_i$ for $i\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now map $\{x,y\}$ to $\{0,1\}$ and other elements $b_i\to a_{i+2}$. That's a bijection $B\to A$.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a fairly explicit bijection from $B$ to $A$.

Let $A_0=\{a_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be a countably infinite subset of $A$, and define $f:B\to A$ by

$$f(b)=\begin{cases}
a_0,&\text{if }b=x\\
a_1,&\text{if }b=y\\
a_{n+2},&\text{if }b=a_n\text{ for some }n\in\Bbb N\\
b,&\text{if }b\in A\setminus A_0\;.
\end{cases}$$

then $f$ is a bijection. (The existence of the set $A_0$ requires some part of the axiom of choice.) The idea is that $f$ leaves $A\setminus A_0$ alone, ‘pushes’ $A_0$ two places over, and inserts $x$ and $y$ into the two places that the ‘pushing’ freed.